# Objective C. Save objects of string in file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've tried to lookup for answers on the Internet but I have found nothing that could help me.

Basically I have these restaurants that I want to save in a file and late read it. I save all the objects in an array for different uses later.

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Restaurant Guide";
Restaurant *restaurant1 = [Restaurant new];
restaurant1.name=@"name1";
restaurant1.mark=@"1";
restaurant1.review=@"good";

Restaurant *restaurant2 = [Restaurant new];
restaurant2.name=@"name2";
restaurant2.mark=@"2";
restaurant2.review=@"bad";

restaurants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:restaurant1, restaurant2, nil];
[restaurants writeToFile:(@"restaurantlist") atomically:NO];
```

But I figured if I do writetofile it won't work because it's not some strings, it's some objects. So how could I proceed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `<NSCoding>` protocol in your Restaurant class and you should implement 2 methods in Restaurant.m file:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"NAME"];
        _mark = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"MARK"];
        _review = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"REVIEW"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"NAME"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.mark forKey:@"MARK"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.review forKey:@"REVIEW"];
}
```

After that you can save your array to file:

```
- (void)saveToFile:(NSArray*)ar
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //data.plist is name of your file, change it if require
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    [ar writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: `writeToFile:atomically:` only works with property list objects, you would have to replace the custom class objects with encoded `NSData` objects. It's easier just to archive the array and call `writeToFile:atomically:` on the archive.

Answer (score -1):

To save a custom object in a file your have to make that class as `NSCoding` complaint.

Here is a good tutorial for it http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data

Basically you have to tell runtime that how your object should be converted into bytes so that it can be saved in a file. And by implementing [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol you does that. By default your `NSDate`, `NSString`, `NSNumber` etc are `NSCoding` compliant so on saving these object we won't get any exception.